# How would I store a video into firebase storage from swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

I'm trying to select a video from a users camera roll which I have done now I"m not sure how to save it to the firebase storage system, how would I got about doing that?

Comment: This isn't a coding service - we are happy to help with an existing issue but you need to post what you've tried. Please see the Firebase Guide on [How To Upload Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) as well as this particularly good read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and this awesome post [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then write some code and let us know where you get stuck so we can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create a reference to your storage

2) Upload your file. (It can be video or audio or images)

```
import FirebaseStorage
var storage = FIRStorage.storage()
var storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://xyz.appspot.com")

let uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(from: localFile, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
  if let error = error 
  {
    //do error handle
  } 
}
```

[The document from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) also explains nicely on how to upload and download contents from firebase storage.